# C# setting a property from different classes more than once

Tags: c#, selenium, properties

I have a IWebElement property that I need to set to a different IWebElement multiple times.  Sometimes from different classes and sometimes multiple times from one class

I have tried so many different ways however it just doesnt seem to work.

I have tried the INotifyPropertyChanged methods I have found on here however I do not think I am implementing correctly.

The below class has an element _LoadMask that needs to be set by different properties on different classes.

```
    public abstract class BasicPage : INotifyPropertyChanged 
    {
        public IWebElement _LoadMask
        {
            get; set; 
        }
       // calls a method from a 'helper' class that waits for element to not be visible
       public void waitForNotVisible()
       {
            WaitElementNotVis(_LoadMask);
       }
    }
```

One of the classes that is setting the property

```
public class someClass : BasicPage
{
        [FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "div[id *= 'loadmask']")]
        public IWebElement LoadMask {
            get { return LoadMask; }
            set { _LoadMask = value; }
        }

        [FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "div[data-selenium-id=\"PagePanelMask\"]")]
        public IWebElement PagePanelMask
        {
            get { return PagePanelMask; }
            set { _LoadMask = value; }
        }

        [FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "div[data-selenium-id=\"EventGridMask\"]")]
        public IWebElement EventGridMask
        {
            get { return EventGridMask; }
            set { _LoadMask = value; }
        }
}
```

The above does not seem to set the property.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? I'm very confused by your description

Comment: *it just doesnt seem to work.* - what doesn't work exactly? Setting `setFoo(value);` in the property sets is fine, are you looking for an OOP way to do this?

Comment: @dman i need those three properties to be able to overwrite a property on a different class.

Comment: @Jeremy this does not work for me. the element does not change.

Comment: Can you please give us a [mcve]? It's hard to understand

Comment: @jeremy does that help?  What i was just trying.